# Creating Java applet using external JARS

Tags: java, jar, applet, external

I've created a Java Applet in Netbeans that uses several external libraries. When I run the applet.java file within Netbeans it works fine and I'm trying to get the same result in a web page.

When I run the automatically created applet.html-file in the build-folder it doesn't load the external library, even though I have specified them in APPLET archive-tag and moved them to the same folder.

Here is my html-file:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="applet/MyApplet.class" width=350 height=200 archive="jcommon-1.0.17.jar,  jfreechart-1.0.14.jar, sqljdbc4.jar"></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The libraries are 3rd-party java (jfreeChart and SQL-JDBC-driver)

Comment: What is your question?  Do you have HTML to load the applet?  If so, copy/paste the content here, along with any reports form the Java console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Creating Java applet using external JARS

Add a reference to them to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.

---

```html
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="applet/MyApplet.class" width=350 height=200 archive="jcommon-1.0.17.jar,  jfreechart-1.0.14.jar, sqljdbc4.jar"></APPLET>
```

Reformatting that gives:

```html
<APPLET 
    codebase="classes" 
    code="applet/MyApplet.class" 
    width=350 
    height=200 
    archive="jcommon-1.0.17.jar,  jfreechart-1.0.14.jar, sqljdbc4.jar">
</APPLET>
```

#### 1.

```
    code="applet/MyApplet.class"
```

Should be the fully qualified name of the class.  If the class name is `MyApplet` and the package is `applet`, that translates to:

```
    code="applet.MyApplet"
```

#### 2.

```
    archive="jcommon-1.0.17.jar,  jfreechart-1.0.14.jar, sqljdbc4.jar">
```

Just checking, is applet.MyApplet in `jcommon-1.0.17.jar`?

#### 3.

```
    codebase="classes"
```

That sounds ominous.  Is this a full-blown web-app with JSP/servlets?  If so, I suspect that path is wrong, in that it is pointing to a place on the server that a client (browser or) applet cannot reach.  Try doing a direct fetch (paste the expected address in the browser address bar, and hit 'enter') on each of the applet Jars, if the `MyApplet.class` is not in a Jar, do a separate check on the loose class file.

Comment: I did this, still it won't load the external jar-files. Thompson, I use the auto-created html file to display the applet in my browser. Applets that are not using external libs are working fine btw

Comment: I added it to the original question

Comment: applet.MyApplet is not in jcommon.jar. It is the main java file that uses the other 3 jars to display some charts. The program itself is not a full-blown web-app. It is a very basic java applet that retrieves records from a database and creates a graph based on those records.

Comment: It is working now. The codebase was correct, the applet/MyApplet.class was also correct. Turns out I didn't have the jars in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

```
package example.jni;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static native void writeHelloWorldToStdout();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
        writeHelloWorldToStdout();
    }
}
```