# Jar a package or individual modules inside package for applet?

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I am converting class files for applet into a jar. The folder is e.g CAR, with individual modules placed into folders like tyres, windows etc inside it. There are also dependencies between some modules.

```
e.g. CAR / tyres
        / windows
        / utils
        / applet
```

The classes are accessed from the applet inside HTML page. We have a main page for CAR.html which can accessed all modules, and individual webpage, tyres.html, windows.html.

I don't have a problem with jarring CAR into CAR.jar but when I tried to jar tyres.jar, windows.jar into separate jars, the applet would not load. The classes package is something like CAR.tyres.xxx so I am not sure if I could jar the individual modules this way.

And do I need to jar CAR.jar after I jar the individual jars? I read that I need to list the dependencies inside the manifest but as the codes existed for sometime, it is a lot of work to do it manually. I am currently using intellj as IDE.

I would like to ask, is it better to jar CAR as CAR.jar or the modules inside it as individual jars?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a jar, the classes have to be in directories corresponding to their packages, so a class `CAR.tyres` (which really, really should be renamed `car.Tyres`) has to be inside a directory named `CAR`. You can make separate jars for your individual classes, but you'll still need the directories inside them.  However, it's generally better to package related classes in a jar when they make sense as a unit; in this case, the parts of the car might go in their own jar, but you should probably group `Tyres` and `Windows` (along with the whole `Car` object) into `car.jar`.

Comment: Lol yes, the CAR, tyres were just for illustrative purposes..but thanks anyway :)

Comment: But I would like to ask, if I make separate jars (with the same directories) using just java jarsigner, is it correct? Because I have problem loading the applet with individual jars :(

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't do it that way, though you have to make sure that the extra jars get loaded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310067/creating-java-applet-using-external-jars

Answer (score 0):

The names and number of jars don't matter, as long as the needed classes can be found in the classpath.

But for the class `com.foo.bar.Test` to be found in one of the jars in the classpath, the `Test.class` file inside the jar must be under `/com/foo/bar`: the structure of the folders inside the jars must match exactly with the structure of the packages.

Comment: Yes, the structure of the folders remained untouched except that it is now .jar instead of folders. But I did not jar CAR folder and only jar the folders inside it.