# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Applet using external jar

Tags: java, html, jsp, applet

I am developing applet code using jsp page.

```
    <APPLET 
      id = "app"
      codebase="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/lib/" 
      code="com.myDemo.test.RunApplet.class" 
      width=100 
      height=50 
      archive="myApp1.jar, myApp2.jar">    
   </APPLET>
```

My directory structure is :

```
DemoProject
  -- src (some classes & packeages)
  -- build
  -- WebContent
       -- css (some css file)
       -- script (some js file)
       -- WEB-INF
            -- jsp(some jsp file)
                 -- myApplet.jsp
            -- lib
                 -- myApp1.jar
                 -- myApp2.jar
```

When i execute myApplet.jsp it will throws the error

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.myDemo.test.RunApplet.class**

I had also apply

```
codebase = "."
codebase = "classes"
codebase = "classes/"
```

but still ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310067/creating-java-applet-using-external-jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that anything in the `WEB-INF` folder is only readable to the back-end servlet, **not** by anything running in the browser including the applet[1].

If the two `jar`s in the `lib` folder are only used by the applet, you can move the folder up to `webcontent` level. If your backend also uses them, you'll have to either copy them or create a servlet to serve them to the front-end.

[1][What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)

Comment: Thank goodness someone who saw this question realized what the likely problem was here.  :)  The OP could try and fetch those Jars directly in the browser address bar to confirm your analysis.

Comment: @billc.cn Thank you for rectified the problem and give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must reference all the jar in < APPLET tag>

like you do:

```
archive="myApp1.jar, myApp2.jar"
```

beware of the location of your jars in archive :

[How to specify correctly codebase and archive in Java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet)

You then must check all dependencies, and include them, one by one:

Solution 1 (if not too many jars): try, detect exception (like this one: com.myDemo.test) , include the jar, and so on.

You must give at least every dependencies.

If your code is rather short (principle for applet), it gives shorter download.

Solution 2 : use some tool: jaranalyser, ...

[How to list dependencies of a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417820/how-to-list-dependencies-of-a-jar)

Solution 3: very simple, but gives very big jar: include everything in one jar

Comment: can you explain it briefly? which kind of dependencies that i have to check! and how to reference all the jar?

Comment: I checked RunApplet.class is exist in myApp1.jar and As per my requirement i can not include everything in one jar.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi , the exception says jvm can not find it. It is the first problem to solve : see link about locations. Second: put at least the jars you need, or refactor them (special jar with least classes). I did that once.