# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier

Tags: java, applet, bouncycastle

I created applet and using bouncycastle class for digital certificate.

I have make some changes for java 8 101 and sign this jar

but after changing it will throws below exception.

**StackTrace :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
... 24 more
```

please help me to resolved this.

Comment: Classloader not find `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier`. have you included `bcprov-jdk15on.1xx.jar` in the applet deployment?

Comment: yes i have added this one.

Comment: Check this for appropiate settings in applet descriptor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310067/creating-java-applet-using-external-jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolved**

Thanks to all
I have tried many thing but didn't find any solution.At last i tried below and its worked.

I made following changes and its work for me.

Added new jar file version is bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.47.jar in lib folder and make entry for this jar file in MANIFEST.MF

After made changes in MANIFEST.MF i have signed both **bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.47.jar** and **applet.jar** file and its work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: please accept this solution to indicate for others that this question is solved...

Comment: this was the solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

What version of bouncy castle are you using? Did you try with latest one? Please also check if your jdk is 32 bit or 64 bit. Hope this helps.